# Подпрыгивает меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь зафиксировать отдельный элемент на странице при прокрутке страницы.
Использую js код:

```
    var position = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var $element = $('.header-st');
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if( scrollTop <= 50 ) { 
    $element.removeClass('hide').removeClass('scrolling');
  } else if( scrollTop < position ) {
    $element.removeClass('hide');
  } else if( scrollTop > position ) {
    $element.addClass('scrolling');
    if( scrollTop + $(window).height() >=  $(document).height() - $element.height() ){
      $element.removeClass('hide');
    } else if(Math.abs($element.position().top) < $element.height()) {
      $element.addClass('hide');
    }
  }
  position = scrollTop;
})
```

На страницах, где высота большая эффект работает хорошо - https://monosnap.com/file/652avLqJnn9onOyWcR9iZdT1DJsFEX

Но если высота небольшая закрепленный элемент постоянно подпрыгивает - страница становитсч нечитабельна https://monosnap.com/file/E3PIWU5UL1IrMQBdKAilYUOdhHIoQh (на скринкате не видно высокую скорость, но страница не читабельна).

Как это исправить?

Comment: сделайте в вопросе [mcve] вашей ошибки

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы закрепляете какой-то элемент - он выпадает из страницы и общая высота резко становится меньше. Это и при достаточной высоте неприятно выглядит. Решение - постарайтесь сохранить высоту страницы. Например, на место "выпавшего" прикрепленного меню вы можете поставить пустой `div` высотой с это меню или добавить в следующий за меню элемент `padding-top` или `margin-top`